# How do I find the pages I add in DotNetNuke?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm using DotNetNuke for the first time and I am unable to locate the URL of the pages I add.

I've attempted Google-ing it and clicking every link to look for the URL being listed somewhere and I'm having no luck. How can I locate these pages?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to the Admin/Pages page (might be called Page Management) you can find a list of all the pages on your site. You can right click on a page and choose "View" to view the page, then copy the URL from the browser